# How database handle this state in transaction?

Tags: database, transactions

I have question about database transaction handling.

If database is shutdown when transaction wrote some data to durable storage but not all, how they resolve this state?

(+) How can client that has automatic retry logic handle state that database finish transaction but disconnected before got response?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common solution for DBMS crash recovery is the one used in [ARIES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_Recovery_and_Isolation_Exploiting_Semantics) algorithm.
Simply put, the database maintains a [write-ahead-log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-ahead_logging) to which all modifications are written before they are applied.
After a crash, the recovery manager undoes the changes that didn't commit and makes sure that all committed changes are written to disk.

(+) The nice thing about relational databases is the fact that they provide [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) guaranties. 
    Because of the [durability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durability_(database_systems)) property, clients know for sure that all successfully committed transactions are reflected on disk and hence there is no need to handle DBMS crash scenario in a special way.

Comment: Is there way to control this?  /  
1) Request Transaction Client -> DB  /  
2) Processing Transaction in DB  /  
3) Disconnect Client Before Got Transaction Response  /  
4) Client try to reconnect to DB  /  
5) Client Retry Request Transaction Again  /  
=> Transaction is requested twice. (Two request -> Two transaction)  /  
Is there way to prevent this?  /  
I think only way to solve this problem is check before Retry Request.  /  
But It is heavy.

Comment: This question is related with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605651/how-to-handle-message-that-failed-to-response-success-but-success-commit-to-dat

Comment: I think you are right. In your scenario, only the DB knows whether the transaction succeeded or not, so it seems that the only way for client to know if retry is required, would be to ask DB.